# What's a good temporary directory to use in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

My ASP.NET application needs to write some temporary files. What folder should I use?

I tried `Path.GetTempPath()` which maps to `C:\Windows\Temp` but surprisingly not all users have access to that path. `IIS_IUSRS` only has read access.

This question is for a general purpose library that should not assume much about the user it runs under. It should not required NTFS permissions.

What is a safe temp path to use under ASP.NET that will always be available for writing?

Answer (score 2):

> What is a safe temp path to use under ASP.NET that will always be
>   available for writing?

Safe temp folder is ***App_Data*** folder inside web application.

ASP.Net Application should not have problem reading and writing to the folder.

It also won't serve files inside that folder to public.

Comment: Is it reliable to find systems configured with write access to the IIS application folder? I'm used to granting IIS_IUSRS read permissions only. `wwwroot` also is only readable. Deploying through xcopy does not make App_Data writable.

Comment: http://www.afterlogic.com/docs/webmail-pro-net/troubleshooting/how-to-assign-correct-permissions-to-app-data-folder-of-webmail-pro-asp-net

Comment: The problem is not configuring any folder to become writable. I'm after finding a folder that just works.

Answer (score 0):

That's what most applications do when people upload avatars or temporary files that you need to store. Just be careful, if a user knows the directory path the file is located in and the file name they are uploading. They can upload an aspx file and it will run under your application identity and that can compromise you. So put some restrictions on file types that can be uploaded.